# Pasar datos entre activitys, sqlserver

Tags: android-studio, activity, android-listview

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual recibo datos de una base de datos, y he llegado al punto de poder listarlos en un ListView, con un HashMap, pero llegado aquí me encuentro que no sé bien bien como pasarlos a otro activity, me explico un poco.

Yo en el listview recibo datos de una tabla sqlserver, donde esta me proporciona simplemente un nombre de cliente,(recibiendo su ID pero sin mostrar) ahora bien, yo quiero en otro activity a raíz de darle click a ese nombre de cliente(por su ID), que me muestre más datos, de ésta o otras tablas haciendo un left join. Creo que esto se hace con un bundle, pero veo muchos posts de estos y son un poco liosos para un novato como yo... dejo mi código para que os situéis, gracias!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    etFiltrar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFiltrrar);

    etFiltrar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            where = etFiltrar.getText().toString();
            mostrarClientes();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMostrar);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            idtext = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.id);
            Log.i("Click", position + " " + idtext.getText());
            // ESTO SOLO MUESTRA UN TOAST CON LA POSITION + ID DE TABLA
            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position= " + position + " ID=" + idtext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            //
            //Aquí quiero pasar los datos de este activity al otro.

        }
    });
    mostrarClientes();
}
public void llamarsegundaActivity(){
    //Esto creo que sería para pasar los datos a un segundo activity, pero no tengo el bundle creado..
    Intent intent = new Intent(Listado.this,ClienteEspecifico.class);
    // Insertar bundle en el intent
    intent.putExtras(mBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void mostrarClientes() {
    HashMap<String, String> clientes = new HashMap<>();
    ConectarHaciaSQL consql;
    consql = new ConectarHaciaSQL();
    Connection cn = consql.conexionBD();
    try {
        Statement pst = cn.createStatement();
        String sel;
        sel = "select CLI.idcliente, CLI.NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 from clientes as CLI" +
                " left join ubicacionesClientes as UC on UC.idcliente = CLI.idCliente ";
        if (where != "") {
            sel = sel + " where CLI.NombreComercial like '%" + where + "%'";
        }
        ;
        sel = sel + " ORDER BY CLI.idcliente ASC";
        //Ejecuta el query del SQL
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sel);
        //Recorre la tabla del SQL
        while (rs.next()) {
            clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
        }

        if (rs != null) {

        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();

        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_items,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

        Iterator it = clientes.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultMap);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("bdagenda", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: no añadas la etiqueta sql-server porque tu problema no esta relacionado con ello. Haces una consulta a BBDD, de acuerdo, pero ahí no te va nada mal, tu problema es pasar datos de una actividad a otra, esa etiqueta no es importante.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres enviar datos de una actividad a otra es muy sencillo. Como dices se hace con un objeto de la clase Intent, el mismo que utilizas para "lanzar" la otra actividad.

Vamos a ver en tu caso como se haría.

Suponemos que quieres cambiar de actividad al pulsar un elemento del listview, se haría así (lo voy a hacer sin llamar a otra función pero tú puedes hacerlo en la función llamarsegundaActivity):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Listado.this,ClienteEspecifico.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Con este código ya podemos ir a la otra actividad pero... queremos enviar datos y ahí no se envía nada entonces, ¿cómo enviamos los datos?

Para enviar los datos, tenemos que "asociarlos" al objeto intent.
Se haría de la siguiente manera (Voy a pasar un entero y un string, tu puedes pasar lo que quieras):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Listado.this,ClienteEspecifico.class);
         intent.putExtra("entero", position);  //Le pasamos por ejemplo el valor position
         intent.putExtra("cadena", "Esta es la cadena que enviamos");
         //En el intent, los datos se adjuntan utilizando clave y valor.
         //En el primer caso la clave es "entero" y en el segundo "cadena"

         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Hasta aquí bien, enviamos a la segunda actividad dos datos, un entero y un string pero ahora, ¿cómo los recogemos en la segunda actividad?

Esto es muy sencillo pero hay que hacerlo bien para no tener errores ya que si no escribimos bien el nombre de la clave no podremos obtener su valor, esto es muy importante.

Para recoger los datos desde la segunda actividad se haría lo siguiente:

```
Bundle bundles = getIntent().getExtras(); //En este objeto es donde están los datos que hemos enviado.
int posit = bundles.getInt("position");
string cad = bundles.getString("cadena");
```

Ahora ya tienes los datos en la ssegunda actividad y pueddes utilizarlos como quieras.

Yo he enviado un entero y un string pero puedes enviar más cosas, ves probanso y verás.

Comment: Me ha quedado bastante claro, lo que ahora viene otra duda, en este ejemplo pasamos texto plano, que lo he conseguido meter en un textview, pero... si yo quiero pasar información que esta en la BBDD, que tendría que hacer consultas por cada valor que quiera pasar? Gracias igualmente!!!

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que me dices. En el intent puedes pasar muchos datos y de muchos tipos a la vez, no un dato por intent, puedes enviar varios y de diferentes tipos. Puedes hacer una consulta a BBDD desde actividad 1 y enviar todos los datos que quieras a ctividad2 en un mismo intent, no acabao de entender lo que preguntas

Comment: Sí justo preguntaba eso que si quería pasar datos de una consulta que hacía de base de datos hacía el otro activity tendría que hacer varias consultas, pero por lo que me dices hago una sola donde el query me devuelva todo lo que necesito y ya lo paso en un mismo intent verdad? gracias!!!

Comment: eso es, con un mismo intent puedes pasar prácticamente lo que quieras.

Comment: Pero entonces en el intent debo pasar la consulta? o cómo sería eso

Comment: no, en el intent pasa los datos una vez hecha la consulta

Comment: Me podrías abrir en chat y me comentas por ahí? ya que esto ya no me queda tan claro y no me sale..

Comment: Voy a ello, bueno, lo intento más bien

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: Tienes que tener un mínimo de reputación para los chats. Intenta hacer un poquito y no habrá problema

Comment: Veamos qué tal, al final saldrá!

Answer (score 1):

Pasamos a la siguiente actividad:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SiguienteActividad.class);
intent.putExtra("nombreVar", laVariable);
startActivity(intent);
```

En la siguiente actividad recogemos la variable:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombreVar");
```

Documentación: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle

Comment: Considera añadir los ejemplos de los enlaces que nos pasas en el cuerpo de la respuesta, de lo contrario se considera una mala respuesta porque los enlaces pueden caer y entonces la respuesta no tendría sentido.

Comment: Actualizado, no sabía cómo ponerlo y quería responderle rápidamente.